# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>

Tags: java, php, function, methods, void

```
package fungsi;


public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        //void artinya hampa
        System.out.println(simpel());
        
        fungsiVoid( input: "apa pun");
    }
    

    private static void fungsiVoid (String input) {
        System.out.println(input);
    }
    
    

    private static float simpel() {
        return 10.0f;
    }
    
    private static int farhan() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I've got errors on this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
    at fungsi.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

What's that mean?

Comment: Has this anything to do with PHP?

Comment: When you call a method, don't label the argument(s). Java does not have named arguments, only positional arguments.

Comment: You should probably start with a Java textbook or the official [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

`fungsiVoid( input: "apa pun");` is not valid java.
Valid is `fungsiVoid( "apa pun");`